# Under the // Texture section of my code I am getting Type 'SpriteName' has no member 'Magic'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Under the `Texture` section of my code I am getting `Type 'SpriteName' has no member 'Magic'`

```
import SpriteKit

let GameParticlesSharedInstance = GameParticles()

class GameParticles {

    class var sharedInstance: GameParticles {
        return GameParticlesSharedInstance
    }

    // MARK: - Public class enum
    internal enum Particles: Int {
        case Magic
    }

    // MARK: - Privat class properties
    private var magicParticles = SKEmitterNode()

    // MARK: - Init
    init() {
        self.setupMagicParticles()
    }

    // MARK: - Setup
    private func setupMagicParticles() {

        // Color
        self.magicParticles.particleColor = Colors.colorFromRGB(rgbvalue: Colors.Magic)

        // Texture
        self.magicParticles.particleTexture = GameTextures.sharedInstance.textureWithName(name: SpriteName.Magic)
    }

    // MARK: - Public functions
    func createParticle(particles particles: Particles) -> SKEmitterNode {
        switch particles {
        case Particles.Magic:
            return self.magicParticles.copy() as! SKEmitterNode
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `textureWithName` is expecting a string. Do you have a struct or enum named SpriteName? Does it have a string associated with the property or case Magic?

Answer (score 0):

Does the enum have string associated with it like so?

```
enum SpriteName {
    case Magic = "Magic"
}
```

You than need to call the rawValue to get the texture string.

```
SpriteName.Magic.rawValue
```

Also as a side note to create a singleton class you can delete the property above your class and replace the class var with

```
static let sharedInstance = GameParticles()
```